# Editmask Powerbuilder 12.6 Build 4121

Tags: asp.net, .net, powerbuilder, powerbuilder.net

I have a problem : I have an EditMask Control that contains 18 numeric values and when I am digiting the value 16th, this control changes the value of the number. 
My current version of Powerbuilder is 12.6 and the build is 4121 released on November 2016.

[I inserted numbers 1 , so it changed by 0 at the end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nsxZ.png) 
[this is the editmask detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sY2iX.png)
Thank you for your soon answer

Comment: You need to provide more detail: code samples/screenshots, in what way does the control change the value, etc.

Comment: Thank you, I will provide as soon as posible.

Comment: Check column type may exceed its maximum length.

Comment: What Eduardo said is likely the issue. What is the data type and precision of the underlying column?